# Ellipsis when printing

Tags: python

When I print my data it will show the first x amount then show `...` then shows the last x amount, I have tried writing this data to csv file and am getting the same thing. I am not sure why it is doing this because I am able to plot the data and have no issues. I was wondering if anybody knows why it will print the ellipsis in the data, and how to prevent it from doing that.

```
import datetime
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import jacks_toolbox.getHistoricalData as dt

rolling_time = 15
num_days = 20

insts = ["7yr", "10yr"]

startTime  = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days = num_days)
endTime    = datetime.datetime.now()

print "Start time: " + startTime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
print "End time: " + endTime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

data = dt.getHistoricalDataByTime(insts, startTime, endTime, minTicks, 5)

dat7 = data["7yr"] 
dat10  = data["10yr"] 

data["7Y10"] = (10 * dat7] - 2 * dat10) / 10
rolling_mean = data["7Y10"].rolling(rolling_time).mean()
print data["7Y10"]
print rolling_mean
```

Comment: Do you have `numpy` or `pandas` imported in `jacks_toolbox`?

Comment: There is an extra bracket , ], after dat7 on the fourth line from the bottom.

Comment: I have both imported in that toolbox.

Comment: So I got it working but not sure if is the best way, I put them both in a pandas DataFrame took the transpose then wrote it to csv and it seemed to work.